# BLE Scan Interval Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10

Is there any way to adjust the BLE advertisement scanning interval on Windows 10 when using `Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`?  When scanning on Android, I see the the advertisements every 100ms, but on Windows 10 using C# I am only getting a `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.Received` event thrown every maybe 700ms.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess not.

The scan parameters are hardcoded to a scan interval of 118.125 ms and scan window of 18.125 ms.

That's why you only get 1/7 of all packets (since 18.125 / 118.125 is ~1/7).

You can however use DeviceIoControl to do it more low level. Here is an example. You have to run this in parallel to your BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher (for example `BetterScanner.StartScanner(0, 29, 29)`). It seems Windows always picks the "best" parameters if two scanners are active at the same time.

DeviceIoControl never returns so I run it in a separate thread. If you need to be able to cancel the scanning you have to use overlapped io to be able to execue CancelIoEx. This code doesn't check for errors, so beware.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

class BetterScanner {
    /// <summary>
    /// The BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS structure facilitates enumerating installed Bluetooth radios.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM
    {
        internal UInt32 dwSize;
        internal void Initialize()
        {
            this.dwSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes an open object handle.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">[In] A valid handle to an open object.</param>
    /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.</returns>
    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the first bluetooth radio present in device manager
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pbtfrp">Pointer to a BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAMS structure</param>
    /// <param name="phRadio">Pointer to where the first enumerated radio handle will be returned. When no longer needed, this handle must be closed via CloseHandle.</param>
    /// <returns>In addition to the handle indicated by phRadio, calling this function will also create a HBLUETOOTH_RADIO_FIND handle for use with the BluetoothFindNextRadio function.
    /// When this handle is no longer needed, it must be closed via the BluetoothFindRadioClose.
    /// Returns NULL upon failure. Call the GetLastError function for more information on the error. The following table describe common errors:</returns>
    [DllImport("irprops.cpl", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ref BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM pbtfrp, out IntPtr phRadio);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct LE_SCAN_REQUEST
    {
        internal int scanType;
        internal ushort scanInterval;
        internal ushort scanWindow;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint dwIoControlCode,
    ref LE_SCAN_REQUEST lpInBuffer, uint nInBufferSize,
    IntPtr lpOutBuffer, uint nOutBufferSize,
    out uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts scanning for LE devices.
    /// Example: BetterScanner.StartScanner(0, 29, 29)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scanType">0 = Passive, 1 = Active</param>
    /// <param name="scanInterval">Interval in 0.625 ms units</param>
    /// <param name="scanWindow">Window in 0.625 ms units</param>
    public static void StartScanner(int scanType, ushort scanInterval, ushort scanWindow)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM param = new BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM();
            param.Initialize();
            IntPtr handle;
            BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ref param, out handle);
            uint outsize;
            LE_SCAN_REQUEST req = new LE_SCAN_REQUEST { scanType = scanType, scanInterval = scanInterval, scanWindow = scanWindow };
            DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x41118c, ref req, 8, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out outsize, IntPtr.Zero);
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested this and it worked like a charm!  Now picking up all the advertisements.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to work.  I'm not sure how to stop the thread though since DeviceIoControl never returns and there is no way to trigger it to return.  Do you think it needs to use Overlapped IO so that it can be async?  I'm out of my element when it comes to device drivers.  Also where did you get the value 0x41118c that you pass to DeviceIoControl?

Comment: I've only done this in C so you need to use some P/Invokes if you use C#. You need to create an OVERLAPPED structure, containing an event object allocated by CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL). Pass a pointer to that structure in the last parameter of DeviceIoControl. If everything's OK, it will return false and GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING. When you want to cancel, call CancelIoEx with the same handle and overlapped structure. Immediately after call GetOverlappedResult with bWait=TRUE. Then you need to call CloseHandle on the event (or simply save it and reuse it next time).

Comment: Is there any ioctl to change the publishing interval? It doesn't seem to be constant. Sometimes using BluetoothLEAdvertisementPublisher will emit every 100ms and sometimes it emits a few advertisements every 5-6 seconds.

Comment: I haven't studied that so don't know.

Comment: Thanks anyway. How did you get the ioctl value for scan interval?

Comment: Works for me! But I'm interested in knowing where did you get that value (0x41118c) from?

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. DeviceIoControl always return false with last error ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER - 1784. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

May be if you set **SamplingInterval** of [SignalStrengthFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.bluetooth.advertisement.bluetoothleadvertisementwatcher.signalstrengthfilter.aspx) frequency will be changed. Try this:

```
BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher=new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();
watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval = 100;
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  Still getting the 700 ms response.

Answer (score 0):

for Windows Universal App try to change StartScanner as following:

```
public static void StartScanner(int scanType, ushort scanInterval, ushort scanWindow) {

    Action<object> action = (object obj) => {
        BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM param = new BLUETOOTH_FIND_RADIO_PARAM();
        param.Initialize();
        IntPtr handle;
        BluetoothFindFirstRadio(ref param, out handle);
        uint outsize;
        LE_SCAN_REQUEST req = new LE_SCAN_REQUEST { 
            scanType = scanType, 
            scanInterval = scanInterval, 
            scanWindow = scanWindow 
        };
        DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x41118c, ref req, 8, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out outsize, IntPtr.Zero);
    };
    Task task = new Task(action,"nothing");
    task.Start();
}
```