# Getting BLE advertisement packets in Windows 10

Tags: windows, bluetooth, win-universal-app, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-mobile

I am currently trying to get Advertisement Packets from Bluetooth LE in Windows 10.

I am developing an Universal Windows Application, thus I am using JavaScript with the following code:

```js
 // Create and initialize a new watcher instance.
var watcher = new Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher();

watcher.signalStrengthFilter.inRangeThresholdInDBm = -126;
watcher.signalStrengthFilter.outOfRangeThresholdInDBm = -126;

watcher.signalStrengthFilter.outOfRangeTimeout = 60000;

watcher.signalStrengthFilter.samplingInterval = 0;
watcher.scanningMode = 1;

watcher.addEventListener("received", onAdvertisementReceived, false);
```

These are my settings to get the most BLE ADV Packets.

In my scenario I have a BLE transponder sending an ADV packet every second, which I can verify on a linux-machine with WireShark.

Strangely I don't get all of these ADV packets with the Windows application.

I will get like 15-20 packets and then there is a 30-60s pause before getting other packets.

All devices (windows-machine, linux-machine and ble-transponder) are within a 1m radius. So I think I should get the same packets on the windows-machine like on the linux-machine, but I don't. Why is that? Are my settings wrong or is there a better way of getting ADV packets?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer at [BLE Scan Interval Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307301/ble-scan-interval-windows-10/37328965).

Basically, Windows instructs the BLE controller to scan for 18.125 ms and then to sleep for 100 ms. That's why you don't get all packets.

Comment: Thanks Emil. Do you have a source for these numbers?

Comment: You can use http://desowin.org/usbpcap/ to see the numbers that are being sent to the Bluetooth controller.

Comment: Okay thanks. Do you know any bypass other than your way mentioned in the other post?

Comment: I know no other method using Microsoft's BLE stack. You can however change BLE stack to something else, maybe https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble. Then you can get more control since it's open source.

Comment: Okay thanks. Just a last question, since I don't know exactly how to see the right values via USBPcap: is it really 18.125 milliseconds, or seconds?

Comment: Milliseconds. See Bluetooth core specification for more info about scan parameters.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. But that doesn't really explain, why I am missing several ADV Packets for ~20seconds?

Comment: Do you have exactly 1000 ms advertisement interval? What you see is not unusual if a small constant times the scan interval is almost a multiple of the advertisement interval + 5ms (due to random delay between 0 and 10 ms). In this case, 17 times 118.125 is 2008.125 ms≈2*1005. So you will probably get each other advertisement packet for some time, then it will drift away so that all packets miss the scan windows. Then after a while the packets will hit the scan window again. Try to slightly change the advertisement interval by some tens of milliseconds and you will observe a different pattern.

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question: I can find the scanInterval parameter via USBPcap but strangely I can't find the scanInterval.