# Unable to BluetoothFindFirstRadio in a Windows 10 Universal App

Tags: winapi, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

A call of the [BluetoothFindFirstRadio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa362786.aspx) function of the Win32 API in a Windows 10 universal app returns ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS (259) while I have an operational bluetooth radio.

I need to call this function because I want to tweak [BLE scan interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307301/ble-scan-interval-windows-10). Any idea? Thanks.

EDIT:
Since BluetoothFindFirstRadio cannot be called from an universal app, I will change my question to: is it possible to adjust the BLE advertisement scanning interval for a Windows 10 universal app (in order to catch all advertisements like we can on iOS or Android devices)? The watcher.SignalStrengthFilter.SamplingInterval property seems to be nonoperational.

Comment: Are you sure this API is supported when targeting the UWP? It's not listed under [Win32 and COM APIs for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592904.aspx) (however, [Alternatives to Windows APIs in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt592894.aspx) does list Bluetooth as a non-supported feature).

Comment: Seems that the solution works for @padonald (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307301/ble-scan-interval-windows-10)

Comment: padonald isn't targeting the UWP in their [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37307301/1889329) either. Windows 10 does not necessarily imply UWP (just that UWP mandates Windows 10).

Comment: You are right @IInspectable, I had not paid attention that I was in a slightly
different scenario. And yes with a classic desktop app the API call works. So, I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a solution: scan for bluetooth devices while watching for BLE advertisements.

The scan can be done like this: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLEClient/cs/Scenario1_DiscoverServer.xaml.cs