# BLE scan interval Windows IoT

Tags: c#, uwp, arm, bluetooth-lowenergy, windowsiot

I have some problems with collecting BLE advertisements using standard BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher in Windows IoT (Rpi3)

Only 30% of packets has been captured.
 I've found a solution here:
[BLE Scan Interval Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307301/ble-scan-interval-windows-10/46653226#46653226) and it works on Windows 10 x64.

But there is one important thing: irprops.cpl which is used in that solution isn't designed for ARM platform.

Is there any way to get it working on Windows IoT (ARM)?

Code VB:

```
    Private watcher As BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
    watcher = New BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher()
    watcher.ScanningMode = BluetoothLEScanningMode.Passive

     Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As NavigationEventArgs)

            AddHandler watcher.Received, AddressOf OnAdvertisementReceived
            watcher.Start()

     End Sub

    Private Async Sub OnAdvertisementReceived(watcher As BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher, eventArgs As BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs)

   'here is the code for counting BLE frames

    Await Me.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, Sub()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, you need to check why the BLE Advertising Packets lost 70%?Please share your codes.

Comment: I added code to my first post. It comes from official Microsoft Sample Pack for UWP.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Bluetooth LE GATT](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/blegatt).In this sample [DeviceWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.devicewatcher) is used to discover Bluetooth LE Devices instead of BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher.In addition, please refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2df584a-17a7-4055-8f8b-7bdc5f6f47dd/win-10-iot-core-ble-devices-and-the-devicewatcher?forum=WindowsIoT) for more infomation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it goes out of the topic. I have problems with recieving  all bluetooth advertisements emitted by my beacon. The code works well on my Windows 10 x64 but Rpi with Win IoT recieves only about 30% advertisements. But there are some researches here: http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/790/Win-10-IoT-Core-Raspberry-Pi3-Bluetooth-Driver-Issue-Workaround I have implemented this solution, and it increased recieved advertisements, but there is still more than 50% of ads which are not collected.