# BLE Scan Interval Windows 10 - DeviceIoControl return false with Last error: 1784 - ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

We need to tweak the BLE scan interval in windows 10 and found the solution in [BLE Scan Interval Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307301/ble-scan-interval-windows-10).

However when calling `DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x41118c, ref req, 8, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out outsize, IntPtr.Zero);` it always return false with the last error is 1784 - ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER. And doesn't seems to affect the scan interval. Is there any suggestion to solve it please?

Comment: Yes, there is other solution used by our Bluetooth Framework (btframework.com). However it requires administratove rights.

Comment: Interesting. Would you please to share some information? Does it offer a trial version for evaluation? Is it support UWP or not?

Comment: Sure, you can download it from the site abd try. Unfortunately no, it does not support UWP applications, only desktop (classic) applications (because of lot of UWP restrictions). Take a look on Beacons demo from the demo package. You should change intervals before starting scanning/advertising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue. Resolved by adding some new registries item under this key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Bluetooth\WinRT\BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher
Add the following values: DWORD: ScanWindow, ScanInterval and adjust it to fit with your configuration.

Comment: Can you provide some example values?

Comment: Can you provide example values you used?

Comment: Did this work without using the "Better scanner" and ioctls? Or did you use both UWP and ioctl. Also, which version on windows did this work on?
I don't see a difference really.

Answer (score 1):

Change structure size in `DeviceIoControl(..)` from 8 to 24. It should help.

```
DeviceIoControl(handle, 0x41118c, ref req, 24, IntPtr.Zero, 0, out outsize, IntPtr.Zero);
```

For Windows Universal App this structure should be defined as follows (it was changed in newer windows 10 compilations):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct LE_SCAN_REQUEST
{
    internal uint unknown1;
    internal int scanType;
    internal uint unknown2;
    internal ushort scanInterval;
    internal ushort scanWindow;
    internal uint unknown3_0;
    internal uint unknown3_1;
}
```

Comment: The new structure works, no longer `ERROR_INVALID_USER_BUFFER`. 
But better use `(uint)Marshal.SizeOf<LE_SCAN_REQUEST>()` instead of manually hardcoding the size.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the new structure:

```
struct ScanRequest1903 {
    uint32_t unknown1;
    uint32_t scan_type; // 0 = passive, 1 = active
    uint32_t unknown2;
    uint16_t scan_interval;
    uint16_t scan_window;
    uint32_t unknown3[2];
};
```

This is for C but you can probably rewrite it to C#.

Comment: I tried but it seems not working. With `ScanType = 1, Scan_Interval=29, Scan_Window=29, unknown1=0, unknown2=0, unknown3 = [0,0]` I got the return bool as False and LastError as 0. Using USBPcap, I don't see any LE Set Scan Parameters command. My Windows version is 1909 build 18363.900.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran into this issue, the answer by @asier70 got me the closest to a working solution. My only change is that I believe the scanWindow and scanInterval fields should be flipped to look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct LE_SCAN_REQUEST
{
    internal uint unknown1;
    internal int scanType;
    internal uint unknown2;
    internal ushort scanWindow;
    internal ushort scanInterval;
    internal uint unknown3_0;
    internal uint unknown3_1;
}
```

I confirmed this by running USBPcap/Wireshark as suggested by @Emil.

Speaking generically, when the first ushort parameter is larger than the second ushort parameter, DeviceIoControl()/GetLastError() returns 0x57 ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

As a side note, I would love to know where the 0x41118c DeviceIoControl code came from. Parsing that value out here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/defining-i-o-control-codes

...results in a function code of 0x0463. It's clear what it does but it would be nice to see its documentation.

(I don't have enough reputation to comment, hence a new answer.)